# Java Desktop Application - Packaging

Tags: java, desktop, packaging

I am developing a Java Desktop Application for Windows 7. It uses MySQL as back-end.
After going through a couple of posts in here [on stackoverflow.com] on packaging, I tried `Launch4j` for wrapping jar file with a exe. It works great. However, the application I am developing gathers environment / user details at the installation time. Environment details like MySQL server home, SMTP server host, and the credentials. Then it saves them in a properties file.

I Would like to know how do I associate this properties file with the exe file generated with Launch4J so that the application uses user specific details and not the default / hardcoded environment details ?

Comment: Do I uderstand correctly: you distribute the Launch4j generated .exe to the user, who runs it ("installation").  At this time a properties file is generated (where?), and the program is installed (to its "installation directory").  If yes, you can have the properties file generated/copied into the same location as the installed program goes, and access it assuming it is in the current directory.  This means that the installed program will have to have its "working directory" set to be the "installation directory" when launched (e.g. run it from that directory).

Comment: Hello Attila,Thank you very much for your reply! Will try it out and update you with the progress. Also, is there a way to dynamically generate the exe file as I wanted to place the properties file in the jar file then wrap it in exe. The properties file contains lot of confidential data.

Comment: Hello Attila, I believe I have figured it out. Thank you for your help! Your suggestion was indeed useful!